# Symfony: user can't logout manually

Tags: php, symfony, session, fosuserbundle, logout

I'm trying to do user check listener, where through user can have only one active session.
Everything is fine but log out is not not working. Here is my config yml

```
remember_me:
    key:      "%secret%"
    lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
    path:     /
    domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
    name: _security_remember_me
logout:                
    invalidate_session: false
    delete_cookies:
    _security_remember_me: { path: /, domain: ~ }
```

And here is my UserProvider

```
<?php
    namespace Application\MainBundle\Security;
    use FOS\UserBundle\Security\UserProvider;

    class EmailProvider extends UserProvider 
    {
        private $container;
        public function setContainer(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container = null)
        {
            $this->container = $container;
        }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function findUser($email)
    {
        return $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($email);
    }

    public function refreshUser(\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface $user)
    {
        if ($user->getActiveSession() !== $this->container->get('session')->getId()) {
            setcookie('_security_remember_me', FALSE, time() - 3600, '/');
            $this->container->get('application.session.handler')->destroy($this->container->get('session')->getId());
            $this->container->get('session')->invalidate();
            $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken(NULL);
        }

        return parent::refreshUser($user);
     }

}
```

Cookie is deleted, but session still alive and make me crazy.

Setcookie() function is my last idea for this, I'm trying with symfony clearCookie() method but still nothing happens.
how can logout user manually?

Comment: Does it work if you set `invalidate_session` to `true`?

Comment: No, invalidate_session can't help in this case, trying with false, true and remove all, but still user is log-in.

Comment: logout: should be on the same level as remember_me:.  Not under it.  Of course it could be a copy paste error.  I'm also used to seeing a path: under logout:.  But maybe that is part of your customization.

Comment: Yep, is copy/paste error. Weirdest think, is this code working "some time", i mean, after random period or clicks (maybe), session has regenerate and everything fine, but not immediately after manually remove session and cookies.